# .NET core DataProtection Keys are not renewing automatically

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, data-protection, asp.net-core-5.0

Last summer I switched to using blob storage and KeyVault to store and encrypt my data protection keys for my simple .NET Core web app.  I did this so users would not have to log back in after I swapped my deployment environment from staging to production.

I used the following page as a guide. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Here is my startup config.

```
services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(new Uri($"{dpSettings.BlobUrl}{dpSettings.SasToken}"))
        .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(new Uri(dpSettings.KeyVaultUrl), new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

References Used

```
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Keys" Version="1.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="BuildBundlerMinifier" Version="3.2.449" />
<PackageReference Include="EPPlus" Version="4.5.3.2" />
<PackageReference Include="HtmlSanitizer" Version="5.0.376" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.17.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" Version="2.17.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureStorage" Version="3.1.13" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="5.0.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.4">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.4">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="5.0.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
<PackageReference Include="Postmark" Version="4.5.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Stripe.net" Version="35.17.0" />
<PackageReference Include="TimeZoneConverter" Version="3.4.0" />
```

It works great but... after 90 days, the site stops working and the following error is reported.

```
Message: An error occurred while trying to encrypt the provided data. Refer to the inner exception for more information.
Stacktrace:
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(Byte[] plaintext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Serialize(AntiforgeryToken token)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.Serialize(IAntiforgeryFeature antiforgeryFeature)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext httpContext)
at...
```

After some troubleshooting I found that the keys.xml file in the blob storage had an expiration date of today.  My understanding is that a new key should be created as the expiration date approaches.  To fix, I just delete the keys.xml file, and then the app creates a new one.  I suppose I could automate this, but I'm pretty sure I shouldn't have to.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For how long you generate blob Sas token?

Comment: The expiration of the SAS token is set for 2100.

Comment: can you plese post your startup ?

Comment: Also please add PackageReference you are using?

Comment: Hi Vova, I've added my references and the relevant part of the startup file is already included.  I'm not sure I can share the full file here.  Is there something specific I should look for?

Comment: @cahresh no what i mean is refferences from proj file

Comment: ok, I've updated the post to include all packages